# if L is in NP-Complete and its complement is also in NP does that mean L is in P? (meaning that P=NP)

Tags: complexity-theory, computability, np-complete, np, p-vs-np

$L^\complement$ = the complement of L

is it true that if
$L\in NPComplete $
and
$L\leq_p L^\complement \rightarrow P=NP$

basically asking if the following statements are correct

$if (L\in NPComplete )  and  (L^\complement \in NP)\rightarrow L\in P\rightarrow P=NP $

Comment: No, but it would prove $NP = coNP$ which is also an unsolved [problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Co-NP). Your question is equivalent to [this one](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/19389/does-np-conp-imply-p-np).

Comment: @plshelp ok so it doesn't mean that L is P right?

Comment: Note that if $L \in \text{NP} - \text{P}$ then $\text{NP} - \text{P} \neq \emptyset$ which implies $P \neq NP$

Comment: @CommandMaster oh right, and what about: if(L∈NPC) and (L∁∈NP)→L∈P ?

Comment: What's NPC? Regardless, the decision version of factorization (does N has a factor less than K other than 1) is known to be both in NP and coNP but not P.

Comment: @CommandMaster ok thanks, NPC=NP-Complete. so does it still not mean L∈P?

Comment: If an NP-complete problem is in coNP it implies NP=coNP, but it doesn't necessarily mean it's in P.

Comment: @CommandMaster alright, thanks!